# Should we always create a TaskExecutor bean named 'taskExecutor' when we use @EnableScheduling

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, concurrency, spring-bean

I have a configuration class without explicitly bean creation method in the class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class PollingAgent {

    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedRate=INTERVAL_RATE, initialDelay = 10000) //setting an initial delay to let the beans get loaded
    void checkAvailableAndStartJob() {
        if(m_messageOnDemand) {
            try {
                LOGGER.info("check job messages and start job if possible");
                jobIdOnDemandSubscriber.StartJobIfMessageAvailable(m_applicationContext);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.info("Scheduler run failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got this log when boot run:
*scheduling-1 : INFO org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor - More than one TaskExecutor bean found within the context, and none is named 'taskExecutor'. Mark one of them as primary or name it 'taskExecutor' (possibly as an alias) in order to use it for async processing: [HappyMondayExecutor, taskScheduler]\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2022-08-05T20:33:41.727269489Z"}*

Should I add TaskExecutor bean named 'taskExecutor' in `PollingAgent`? :

```
@Bean
public Executor taskExecutor() {
    return Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
}
```

Why not the spring framework create a bean named 'taskExecutor' automatically when using @EnableScheduling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the info message is happening because you have more than one `TaskExecutor` bean declared in your application context.

From [`@EnableAsync` javadoc:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html)

> By default, Spring will be searching for an associated thread pool
> definition: either a unique TaskExecutor bean in the context, or an
> Executor bean named "taskExecutor" otherwise. If neither of the two is
> resolvable, a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor will be used to process async
> method invocations. Besides, annotated methods having a void return
> type cannot transmit any exception back to the caller. By default,
> such uncaught exceptions are only logged.

The log message is just an info saying "Hey, I've found two `TaskExecutor` declarations. Are you sure none of these was intended to be the executor for your `@Async` tasks?"

Anyway, as said in the quote above, a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` bean have been designated for your `@Async` annotated methods executions.

Now for your question:

> Why not the spring framework create a bean named 'taskExecutor'
> automatically when using @EnableScheduling?

Well, the `@Scheduled` annotated methods relies on a Scheduler. Now, a quote from [`@EnableScheduling` javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html):

> By default, Spring will search for an associated scheduler definition:
> either a unique TaskScheduler bean in the context, or a TaskScheduler
> bean named "taskScheduler" otherwise; the same lookup will also be
> performed for a ScheduledExecutorService bean. If neither of the two
> is resolvable, a local single-threaded default scheduler will be
> created and used within the registrar.

Spring does not create a bean called "taskExecutor". It just creates, as said above, a local single-threaded default scheduler.

Comment: Is `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` one of two `TaskExecutor` declarations found by Spring framework? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, since I have the `@EnableScheduling`, should I remove `@EnableAsync`?

Comment: @lightrek. . .`@EnableScheduling` does different things than `@EnableAsync`. The `@EnableScheduling` enables detection of `@Scheduled` methods. The `@EnableAsync` enables async method execution. You can use both, depending on your needs. And no, the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` is not one of the task executor found by Spring. You're sure you have no other `@Configuration` class that define a `TaskExecutor` bean? This is what seems like. The answer posted by sjy down below is correct. This code should work without any warning from Spring.

Comment: Thanks! I do have another Configuration class that defines a TaskExecutor bean, but that is the only one I have, why the spring complains that I have two `TaskExecutor` declarations?

Comment: Moreover, based on what you said, if I only use `@EnableScheduling` without `@EnableAsync`, how can the scheduled task run? (I suppose the scheduled task should run on a separate thread asyncrously)

Comment: @lightrek. . . 1st: I don't know exactly why Spring is complaining about this. My best guess is that something defined in the context through `@EnableScheduling` or through the `@EnableAsync` (or used by one of these) are competing with each other and / or with your TaskExecutor definition.

Comment: 2nd: This is exactly what happens. The `@Scheduled` methods already run in a separated thread. There's no need to annotate a method with `@Async` and `@Scheduled`. If you want to run a scheduled task, then use the `@Scheduled`. The `@Async` is intended to be used for other cases, not for scheduled tasks. As I said in the answer: *a local single-threaded default scheduler will be created and used within the registrar* -- a thread is used to execute the Scheduled Task. Of course, the scheduler relies on a `TaskExecutor` to execute, but the way it is created differs from the `@EnableAsync`.

Comment: If you want to take more control over this behavior, you can implement the `ScheduleConfigurer` interface and then set a custom task executor to the `ScheduledTaskRegistrar`.

Answer (score -1):

Without any task executor the below code will run .
Please check which version of spring boot you are using .

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class PollingAgent {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PollingAgent.class);

    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedRate=1000, initialDelay = 10000) //setting an initial delay to let the beans get loaded
    void checkAvailableAndStartJob() {
        log.info("started");
    }

   }
```

Comment: Yes, it runs, but the log from the boot run seems indicating what I did is not correct